# Laravel & vue.js values to array

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

I'm using vue.js in Laravel.

I've 3 table's.

```
Article  
Location 
article_location (pivot table)
```

If I want to convert a location articles to json so I can pass it to vue How could I do this?

```
 <div class="container">

        Location->article  //all articles of a location to json

        <template id="ln-data">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="value in list">
                    @{{ value.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </template>

        <script>
        Vue.config.debug = true;

        Vue.component('data', {
            template: '#ln-data',
            props:['list'],

            created() {
                this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
            }
        })

        new Vue({
            el: 'body'
        });
        </script>
```

How could I do this?

EDIT --

Controller:

```
$location = location::all();
return view('locationproducts')->with('location',$location);
```

View:

```
  <div class="container">
            <data list="{{ $location->article()->toJson() }}"></data>
    </div>
```

Location model:

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\article','article_location');
}
```

Error:

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81: Method article does not
>   exist. (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/project/resources/views/locationproducts.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `toJson()` method, to convert a model to JSON, you may use the `toJson` method. Like `toArray`, the `toJson` method is recursive, so all attributes and relations will be converted to JSON :

```
$location->articles()->toJson();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my edit. Any idea why that error shows up?

Comment: You're welcome, googled a little i can see that the issue is related by forms but i can't find any quick answer, i suggest to add another question specific to this issue with clear description and more specific code.